# Error Unity at UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () [0x00000]

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have an error each time I press to a certain button on android build. Event system is present, buttons do work perfectly in the editor, I tried it multiple times. It seems that only those buttons create the problem. Others DO work correctly in the build. Any suggestions?
Logcat log when the button is pressed:

```
    2023/02/15 16:51:33.167 3033 3062 Error Unity   at UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
2023/02/15 16:51:33.167 3033 3062 Error Unity   at UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[T] (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents+EventFunction`1[T1] functor) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
2023/02/15 16:51:33.167 3033 3062 Error Unity   at UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule.ProcessTouchPress (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData pointerEvent, System.Boolean pressed, System.Boolean released) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
2023/02/15 16:51:33.167 3033 3062 Error Unity   at UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule.ProcessTouchEvents () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
2023/02/15 16:51:33.167 3033 3062 Error Unity   at UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule.Process ()
```

I tried deleting eventsystem, creating a new one and then building it again but no success

Comment: Which button and what does the button do?

Comment: Button is selecting a team member, opens a team selection menu. I did check that reference is not null. And it does work in the editor. Idk what's up with ui eventsystem here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys, it turns out that I was fetching the data from empty Json file so, in unity don't forget to create the default Json file. So it's basically a null reference exception